# How to claim multiple exisiting pvc's AFTER initial creation made by NATS helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I have a NATS Helm Chart that when initially ran will build the needed statefulsets and pvc's (provided I supply the pv's)

3 Replica Statefulsets (created by the helm chart)

- nats-0
- nats-1
- nats-2

3 corresponding Persistent Volumes (provided by me and placed in the infra folder).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nats-pv-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /data/my-nats-pv-0
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nats-pv-0
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /data/my-nats-pv-0
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nats-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /data/my-nats-pv-2
```

3 Resulting Persistent Volume Claims (Generated by helm chart)

- nats-js-pvc-nats-0
- nats-js-pvc-nats-1
- nats-js-pvc-nats-2

---

Yet, when I want to reconnect to them after a restart of the cluster, I can't get them to claim the previously created pvcs'.

Instead, I get indefinitely stalled pods that, according to the `kubectl describe nats-/*(POD#)*/` cannot find the PVC. This is the portion of the helm chart responsible for pvc claiming. The pvs and pvcs are persistent and bound together. How do I make the NATS Helm chart create new stateful sets that will claim the existing PVCs? I am NOT sure that I am filling out the `existingClaims` section right. THANKS!

I have tried the following:

Attempt #1

```yaml
    ############################
    #                          #
    #  Jetstream File Storage  #
    #                          #
    ############################
    fileStorage:
      enabled: true
      storageDirectory: /data

      # Set for use with existing PVC
      existingClaim: nats-js-pvc-$(POD_NAME)
                  #jetstream-pvc
      claimStorageSize: 1Gi

      # Use below block to create new persistent volume
      # only used if existingClaim is not specified
   #   size: 1Gi
   #   storageClassName: standard
   #   accessModes:
   #     - ReadWriteOnce
      # annotations:
      # key: "value"

    # Use below if fileStorage is not enabled but you are persisting
    # data using an alternative to PVC (e.g. hostPath)
    # These set the corresponding jetstream configuration in nats.conf.
    # store_dir: "/data"
    # max_file: "10Gi"
```

Attempt #2

```yaml
    ############################
    #                          #
    #  Jetstream File Storage  #
    #                          #
    ############################
    fileStorage:
      enabled: true
      storageDirectory: /data

      # Set for use with existing PVC
      existingClaim:
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-0
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-1
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-2
                  #jetstream-pvc
      claimStorageSize: 1Gi


      # Use below block to create new persistent volume
      # only used if existingClaim is not specified
   #   size: 1Gi
   #   storageClassName: standard
   #   accessModes:
   #     - ReadWriteOnce
      # annotations:
      # key: "value"

    # Use below if fileStorage is not enabled but you are persisting
    # data using an alternative to PVC (e.g. hostPath)
    # These set the corresponding jetstream configuration in nats.conf.
    # store_dir: "/data"
    # max_file: "10Gi"
```

Attempt #3

```yaml
    ############################
    #                          #
    #  Jetstream File Storage  #
    #                          #
    ############################
    fileStorage:
      enabled: true
      storageDirectory: /data

      # Set for use with existing PVC
      existingClaim: 
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-0 
        claimStorageSize: 1Gi
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-1 
        claimStorageSize: 1Gi
      - name: nats-js-pvc-nats-2
        claimStorageSize: 1Gi


      # Use below block to create new persistent volume
      # only used if existingClaim is not specified
   #   size: 1Gi
   #   storageClassName: standard
   #   accessModes:
   #     - ReadWriteOnce
      # annotations:
      # key: "value"

    # Use below if fileStorage is not enabled but you are persisting
    # data using an alternative to PVC (e.g. hostPath)
    # These set the corresponding jetstream configuration in nats.conf.
    # store_dir: "/data"
    # max_file: "10Gi"
```

Attempt #4

```yaml
    ############################
    #                          #
    #  Jetstream File Storage  #
    #                          #
    ############################
    fileStorage:
      enabled: true
      storageDirectory: /data

      # Set for use with existing PVC
      existingClaim: [nats-js-pvc-nats-0,nats-js-pvc-nats-1,nats-js-pvc-nats-2]
                  #jetstream-pvc
      claimStorageSize: 1Gi

      # Use below block to create new persistent volume
      # only used if existingClaim is not specified
   #   size: 1Gi
   #   storageClassName: standard
   #   accessModes:
   #     - ReadWriteOnce
      # annotations:
      # key: "value"

    # Use below if fileStorage is not enabled but you are persisting
    # data using an alternative to PVC (e.g. hostPath)
    # These set the corresponding jetstream configuration in nats.conf.
    # store_dir: "/data"
    # max_file: "10Gi"
```

Edit #1: Also tried nats-js-pvc-$(POD_NAME), nats-js-pvc-(POD_NAME)

Comment: Hello did you manage to resolve this? And if so could you share it?